# Sub category is different front-end when checking back-end

Tags: category, sorting

On the front-end of my site I have a sidebar which shows the subcategorys
But when I change the "sortorder" in the back-end the front-end keeps its position.

[image]
[image]

How can I change the way it orders it the same as back-end?

My .phtml
/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/catalog/navigation/leftnav.phtml

```
<div class="block left-categorys">
    <?php
        $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
        echo '<div class="block-title"><h2>'.$currentCat->getName().'</h2></div>';

        if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() ){
            $loadCategory = $currentCat;
        }else{
            $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getId());
        }
        $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());  
        if(count($subCategories) > 1){
            echo '<div class="block-content left-categorys-container">';
            foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId ){
                $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
                if($cat->getIsActive()){
                    echo '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with using a collection. And for best practice probably move all the logic (like retrieving the collection) to a block class

```
<div class="block left-categorys">
    <?php
        $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
        echo '<div class="block-title"><h2>'.$currentCat->getName().'</h2></div>';

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCat->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
        ->addUrlRewriteToResult();

        if($collection->getSize()){
            echo '<div class="block-content left-categorys-container">';
            foreach ($collection as $category ){
                echo '<a href="'.$category->getUrl($category).'">'.$category->getName().'</a>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: my sidebar goes blank after using this code :(

Comment: Please enable error output or check apache error logs and let me know what the error is

Comment: @user123 Ah found the issue, the error should be fixed now

Comment: Still some error: [Mon Feb 23 15:59:10 2015] [error] [client 80.xxx.162.1xx] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /home/x/domains/x.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/catalog/navigation/leftnav.phtml on line 12, referer: http://www.x.nl/

Comment: on line 12: if(collection->getSize()){

Comment: AH it needs to be: $collection / now I do get some output but the name/title isn't output. '.$category->getName().'

Comment: This one was in the old one but doesn't work  '.$cat->getName().'

Comment: please add `->addAttributeToSelect('name')` to also retrieve the name. I've updated the answer with it